# Azure Cognitive Search Document Name Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Cognitive Search and would like to know if there is a way to have the document name also be searchable. I can not find the specific value that is associated to document name within the Azure documentation.

Anyone run into this problem before? This is what I currently have:

```json
{
  "name": "title",
  "type": "Edm.String",
  "searchable": "true",
  ...
}
```

Is "title" the correct value? I also tried "documentName" as ChatGPT suggested that but I am pretty sure it was wrong since I am not able to search using the name of the document, only the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make sure `"searchable": "true"` and for the `"name": "metadata_storage_name":

```json
{
  "name": "metadata_storage_name",
  "type": "Edm.String",
  "searchable": "true",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The index looks correct. I would suggest that the code used to retrieve the documents is the issue here. Make sure you're not tied exclusively to the vector index

Comment: My index does not have a vector search configuration attached to it.